# How to automate capturing output data with LLDB if that data is only available on return of a C function?

Tags: c, debugging, lldb

I have compiled binary without any source code but I know that it contains a C function with the following signature

```
void generateMoreData ( char * destination, long size )
```

The symbol of that function is visible in the LLDB debugger and I would like to capture all the generated data.

Currently I know that I can capture the data the following way:

1. I set a breakpoint `break set -n generateMoreData`
2. Once the breakpoint is hit, I check the values of `$rdi` and `$rsi` because the x86_64 ABI for System V (used by Linux, BSD, macOS, and Solaris) passes the first two arguments in these registers.
3. Then I continue until the function returns using `thread step-out`.
4. Finally I can dump the data using `x -c COUNT ADDRESS` where `COUNT` is the value of `$rsi` and `ADDRESS` the value of `$rdi` as seen in step (2)

This works okay but I would like to automate that entire process and run into two problems:

- Problem A: Only when entering the function `$rdi` and `$rsi` contain the values I need but not anymore when the function returns as these registers are used by the function and thus lose their initial values.
- Problem B: I can set commands to be executed when a breakpoint is hit using `break command add` but these commands cannot contain `thread step-out` because this command continues execution and the first command that continues execution stops processing of breakpoint commands, so any commands set after this command are never executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier way to figure out the address for the breakpoint for step B is to make use of the fact that the pc value in a parent frame is always the return pc to that frame.  So we can have breakpoint 1's command figure it out.  Since you aren't using any information from the current frame when you hit the second breakpoint, you don't care whether you stop at or just after the returns.

You do have to remember to clear the old one first, but that's easy to do using named breakpoints in lldb:

```
break set -G true -n generateMoreData --skip-prologue false
breakpoint name configure SecondBreakpoint -G true -C "x -o generateMoreData.txt --append-outfile -c \`$size\` $destination" -C "break delete SecondBreakpoint"
break command add 1
> expr long $destination = $arg1
> expr long $size = $arg2
> up
> break set -N SecondBreakpoint -a $pc 
> DONE
```

Note we don't have to add the commands to the breakpoint we make because I added it to the name, so the new breakpoint will inherit them from that name.

I also used `$arg1` and `$arg2` instead of `$rsi` and `$rdi`.  That's just a convenient lldb alias in case you can't remember which is which...

Also, solving this gets harder if this function is likely to be called from multiple threads.  Then you need to grab the current thread and set a thread specific breakpoint.  Also if this is going to get called recursively, you'll have to make different $size and $destination values per returning frame.

If you start trying to handle those sorts of issue, it's probably better to use a Python callback for the breakpoints.  Then instead of storing the data you want to print on return in the process, as Mecki's clever solution does, you could maintain a little Python data structure that remembers $size & $destination for each frame/thread combo, and do the right printing when each call returns.

Comment: Very interesting solution. Setting a break point from within a break point is something I've never came up with so far. And I also thought about a Python solution but my Python skills are very limited.

Answer (score 1):

The overall solution for that problem is to actually use two breakpoints.

First we solve problem A by storing the desired values to LLDB variables:

```
break set -G true -n generateMoreData
break command add 1
> expr long $destination = $rsi
> expr long $size = $rdi
> DONE
```

`-G true` makes sure that the program continues automatically after executing all the commands and with `expr` it is possible to store register content to variables which we name `$destination` and `$size`.

To solve problem B, we need another breakpoint at the return instruction of `generateMoreData`. In case `generateMoreData` has more than one return instruction, we'd need a breakpoint at each of them but let's assume it is a rather simple function and only has a single breakpoint as often is the case.

First we need to break into that function, so we just set a normal breakpoint on it and let the debugger hit it. Then we can disassemble the function using `dis`. The output may look similar to the one below:

```
->  0x7fff76be0bac <+0>:   pushq  %rbp
    0x7fff76be0bad <+1>:   movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x7fff76be0bb0 <+4>:   pushq  %r14
    0x7fff76be0bb2 <+6>:   pushq  %rbx
    0x7fff76be0bb3 <+7>:   subq   $0x40, %rsp
    :
    0x7fff76be0c5f <+179>: popq   %r14
    0x7fff76be0c61 <+181>: popq   %rbp
    0x7fff76be0c62 <+182>: retq   
    0x7fff76be0c63 <+183>: nop
```

The absolute addresses are often useless as they may change between two runs of the program (e.g. because of ASLR, Address Space Layout Randomization), the interesting addresses are the relative ones (`<+...>`). Knowing that there is a return at `+182` allows us to set a breakpoint there and so we way can solve problem B:

```
break set -G true -n generateMoreData -R 182
break command add 2
> x -o generateMoreData.txt --append-outfile -c `$size` $destination
> DONE
```

`-R` sets a relative offset in bytes. The captured data is written to `generateMoreData.txt` for later inspection (`-o` sets an output file and `--append-outfile` makes sure that new data is appended instead of overwriting existing one).

Now just run the program and at the end you can inspect all the generated data in the output file.